# How do I cleanly exit from a program that is using Poco::Net::TCPServer?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

My server start a `Poco::Task` which, in turn, start two `TCPServer`.

```
int TBServer::main(const std::vector<std::string>& args) {
  if (!m_helpRequested) {
    TaskManager tm;
    tm.start(new ServerTask());
    waitForTerminationRequest();
    tm.cancelAll();
    tm.joinAll();
  }
  return Application::EXIT_OK;
}

POCO_SERVER_MAIN(TBServer)
```

The Task is the following:

```
void ServerTask::runTask() {

  AutoPtr<PropertyFileConfiguration> pConf;

  try {
    pConf = new PropertyFileConfiguration("TBServer.prop");

    TCPServer local_svr();
    TCPServer remote_svr();

    local_svr.Start(pConf->getInt("local_svr_port", 5000));

    UINT mode = pConf->getInt("svr_mode", 0);

    // Socket mode
    if (mode & 0x01)
      remote_svr.Start(pConf->getInt("remote_svr_port", 8000));

    while(!isCancelled())
    {
      // Do nothing here...the logic is inside the TCPServer classes
      sleep(500);
    }
  }
  catch (Poco::Exception e) {
    log << e.message() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The `TCPServe` class here is a simple wrapper around `Poco::Net::TCPServer`.

The problem here is that, when I close the application, I get an access violation, maybe due to terminate the `TCPServer` and `TCPConnection` in a wrong way.

This is the call stack:

```
  ntdll.dll!_RtlpWaitForCriticalSection@4()  + 0x5b byte    
  ntdll.dll!_RtlEnterCriticalSection@4()  + 0x46 byte   
> TBServer.exe!Poco::MutexImpl::lockImpl()  Riga 76 + 0xc byte  C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::FastMutex::lock()  Riga 260    C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::Net::TCPServerDispatcher::release()  Riga 113  C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::Net::TCPServer::~TCPServer()  Riga 75  C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::Net::TCPServer::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x2b byte    C++
  TBServer.exe!TCPServer::~TCPServer()  Line 86 + 0x37 byte C++
  TBServer.exe!TCPServer::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x2b byte   C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::ReleasePolicy<Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactory>::release(Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactory * pObj=0x0141fa8c)  Line 90 + 0x34 byte    C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactory,Poco::ReferenceCounter,Poco::ReleasePolicy<Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactory> >::release()  Line 404 + 0xc byte    C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactory,Poco::ReferenceCounter,Poco::ReleasePolicy<Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactory> >::~SharedPtr<Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactory,Poco::ReferenceCounter,Poco::ReleasePolicy<Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactory> >()  Line 160  C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::Net::TCPServerDispatcher::~TCPServerDispatcher()  Line 99 + 0x1a byte  C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::Net::TCPServerDispatcher::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x2b byte  C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::Net::TCPServerDispatcher::release()  Line 115 + 0x3a byte  C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::Net::TCPServer::~TCPServer()  Line 75  C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::Net::TCPServer::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x2b byte    C++
  TBServer.exe!TCPServer::~TCPServer()  Line 86 + 0x37 byte C++
  TBServer.exe!ServerTask::runTask()  Line 114 + 0xf byte   C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::Task::run()  Line 85 + 0xf byte    C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::PooledThread::run()  Line 215 + 0x15 byte  C++
  TBServer.exe!Poco::ThreadImpl::runnableEntry(void * pThread=0x0122089c)  Line 245 + 0x13 byte C++
```

---

#### THE QUESTION

- How can I *"wait"* for all threads to end before destroy objects?

---

#### TEST PROJECT

If someone would check this situation I prepared a little project which demonstrates the issue. It can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7QZixdvKHVORmw2MWljYmZXcUk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: what version of `Poco` are you using?

Comment: I'm using Poco v1.5.2-all

Answer (score 2):

#### SOLUTION

You'll need to call `Poco::Net::TCPServer::stop` on your instances of this type before exiting the scope of your function, otherwise they won't destruct properly - and you get the diagnostic you posted.

<sub>**Note**: Since you already have a wrapper, place a call to `wrapped_server.stop ()` in the destructor of that type to handle it automatically.</sub>

---

#### EXPLANATION

Inside `Poco::Net::TCPServer::start` a new thread is created that waits for, and accepts, incoming connections, and that thread needs time to clean-up after itself.

By just calling the destructor, without calling `.stop`, this other thread will try to access memory that is no longer available.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Filip. I'm using Poco v1.5.2-all. In a first implementation I have put a local_svr.Stop() after the while{} has terminated but I've got the same behavior. In the wrapper destructor there is already a call to m_tcp_server->stop() (sorry to not have post the code). Is there a way to 'Join()' the TCPServer thread?